# How to have a clickable link in a textview, within a custom listview and still have clickable listview

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, clickable

I have a "setOnItemClickListener" for a custom listview that I made. When the row is clicked, a method runs. That works. I am able to get a link to be clickable in the textview from within the listview by using this...

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

But then the row becomes unclickable. Any row that does not have a link in it can be clicked. The autoLink is overriding the "setOnItemClickListener" for the listview. How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` with focusable elements disable the click event on the `ListView` itself

To overcome it..

Add :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to your listview row's root layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does not make the row clickable if there is a link in it.

Comment: That worked. I misunderstood what you meant. Thanks for the edit and clarification.